# I'm getting an error building a sveltekit project

Tags: rollupjs, sveltekit, vite

I'm building a sveltekit project. One thing I've done is created a custom type of file which is converted to a *.svelte file upon building or running the development server. By default, sveltekit includes the rollup extension rollup-plugin-dynamic-import-variables which is trying to parse my custom file (who knows why?) and throwing an "unexpected token" error. I'm trying to configure that extension to ignore my custom files, but so far without success. Here is my attempted svelte.config.js file:

```
// @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config}
var config;

import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';

import dynamicImportVariables from 'rollup-plugin-dynamic-import-variables';

config = {
  kit: {
    // --- hydrate the <div id="svelte"> element in src/app.html
    target: '#svelte',
    adapter: adapter({
      pages: 'build',
      assets: 'build',
      fallback: null
    }),
    vite: {
      plugins: [
        dynamicImportVariables({
          warnOnError: true,
          exclude: '**'
        })
      ]
    }
  }
};

export default config;
```

To be honest about it, I don't use dynamic imports anywhere and therefore would accept as a solution the complete disabling of the extension. But anything that would get it to ignore my custom files would also work.

Comment: The file in question is named **index.starbucks** and it contains:

#starbucks webpage
h1 The Wizard of Oz

If you place such a file in your src/routes folder, you'll get the following error:

Unexpected token (1:0)
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:0)
    at Object.pp$5.raise (C:\Users\johnd\oz\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-36bf480c.js:47485:13)
    at Object.pp.unexpected (C:\Users\johnd\oz\node_modules\vite\dist
...etc.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:** SvelteKit 1.0.0-beta now requires pages/endpoints to follow a specific naming pattern, so explicit file exclusion should no longer be needed.

SvelteKit specially handles files in the `routes/` directory with the following filenames (note the leading `+` in each filename):

- [`+page.svelte`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#page-page-svelte)
- [`+page.js`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#page-page-js)
- [`+page.server.js`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#page-server-js)
- [`+error.js`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#error)
- [`+layout.svelte`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#layout-svelte)
- [`+layout.js`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#layout-js)
- [`+layout.server.js`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#layout-server-js)
- [`+server.js`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#server-js)

All [other files are ignored](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#other-files) and can be colocated in the `routes/` directory.

If, for some reason, you need to have a file that has a special name shown above, it's currently not possible to exclude that file from special processing.

---

*Original outdated answer:*

The `rollup-plugin-dynamic-import-variables` is actually included by Vite. To configure Vite's plugin, set [the `build.dynamicImportVarsOptions` property](https://vitejs.dev/config/#build-dynamicimportvarsoptions):

```js
// svelte.config.js
/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
  kit: {
    // hydrate the <div id="svelte"> element in src/app.html
    target: "#svelte",
    vite: {
      build: {
        dynamicImportVarsOptions: {
          exclude: [/node_modules/, /\.starbucks$/],
        },
      },
    },
  },
}

export default config
```

**But that's not going to fix the problem...**

SvelteKit processes all files under `src/routes/` so that they're automatically imported in the output application (in `.svelte-kit/build/app.js`), which will result in the same error.

### Option 1: Private modules

You could exclude a `src/routes/*.starbucks` file by making it a [private module](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#routing-private-modules), which has a leading underscore in the filename:

```
src/routes/_home.starbucks 
src/routes/_index.starbucks 
src/routes/index.svelte
```

### Option 2: Move files outside `src/routes`

Alternatively, move those `*.starbucks` files outside of `src/routes/` (e.g., into `src/starbucks/` or `src/lib/`):

```
src/routes/index.svelte
src/starbucks/home.starbucks 
src/starbucks/index.starbucks 
src/lib/home.starbucks 
src/lib/index.starbucks
```

Comment: Thank you, tony19, especially after my (not for the first time) complaining about stack overflow changing how I format my comments. I've never heard of "private modules". I would have preferred the option to configure which files get included/excluded, but for now, option 1 seems the best. Meanwhile, I had used (and will for now continue to use) a variation of option 2. I create an entirely separate directory named '%src', which parallels the 'src' directory. See, I'm converting more than just *.starbucks files.

Comment: Any file of a type that I want to convert that's found anywhere in the %src tree is converted, then copied to the corresponding location in the 'src' directory. The advantage to naming my parallel directory %src is that given a full path to a file I want to convert, I can simply replace '%' with '' in the full path and get the corresponding full path to where the converted file goes. Anyway, thanks again for the help.